# Python Datetime parsing using AM not matching due to " "

Tags: python, pandas, datetime

I am trying to convert a string that includes a date to a datetime object.

How it looks: '01/01/2017 01:00:00 AM'

What I am currently using:

```
#df['date'] =  pd.to_datetime(df['date'], format="%m/%d/%Y %I:%M:%S %p")
```

I get the following error message.

```
ValueError: time data ' ' does not match format '%m/%d/%Y %I:%M:%S %p' (match)
```

Thank you in advance for your help

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow.  The obvious explanation is that `df['date']` contains a string that is just a single space.  I can't know if this is true as you haven't told us where that value comes from, but it's a logical assumption given what you've shown us.

Comment: the first row of df['date'] is '01/01/2017 01:00:00 AM'

Comment: Are all the rows valid dates?  Are you sure that at least one of them isn't somehow blank?  I could very easily be wrong, but I don't read that error message as the problem being that there's an extra space IN a date string.  Rather, it says to me that it's unable to convert a string that is JUST a single space to a datetime object.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I didn't want to spend the time to construct a Pandas example.  But I figured that Pandas would be using Python's `strftime` function to parse dates.  So I just created an example with that function

This line of code:

```
datetime.strptime(' ', '%m/%d/%Y %I:%M:%S %p')
```

gives me the error

```
ValueError: time data ' ' does not match format '%m/%d/%Y %I:%M:%S %p'.
```

Same exact error. So somewhere you think you've got a valid date string, but you actually have a string that's a single space character;

Comment: I miss things like this quite often.  You get your head thinking in a certain direction, and you stop looking for what the evidence you have is actually telling you :)

Comment: *"I didn't want to spend the time to construct a Pandas example."* - well, a `pd.to_datetime(df["date"], errors="coerce")` would do the trick.

Comment: @FObersteiner - Cool.  What I really meant was "I didn't want to spend the time to instal Pandas and then try to remember how it works".  If I'd had your help available, maybe I'd have gone that way.